# Bootstrap Nav bar doesn't work properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I've looked over this code about ten times now and I can't seem to get the nav bar to work properly when on mobile. It just doesn't work when I click on it.

Edit: We're using React to render the navbar to the page. Added the entire JS file so you can take a look.

```js
var NavLoggedIn = React.createClass({

      render: function() {
          return (



              //  <div className ="navcontainer">
              //         <nav> 
              //         <a href='/index'>Index</a>
              //             <a href='/pod-search'>POD Search</a>
              //              <a href='/book-now'>Book Now</a>
              //               <a href='/current-bookings'>Current Bookings</a>
              //             <a href='/historic-bookings'>Historic Bookings</a>
              //             <a href='/contact-us'>Contact Us</a>
              //             <a href='/pod-profile'>pod profile</a>
              //             <a href='/my-profile'>My profile</a>
              //             <a href='/login'>Log In</a>
              //         </nav>
              //     </div>



              < nav className = "navbar-fixed-top  navbar-inverse"
              id = "navColor" >
              < div className = "container-fluid" >
              < div className = "navbar-header" >
              < button type = "button"
              className = "navbar-toggle collapsed"
              data - toggle = "collapse"
              data - target = "#navbar"
              aria - expanded = "false"
              aria - controls = "navbar" >
              < span className = "icon-bar" > < /span>
            <span className="icon-bar"></span >
              < span className = "icon-bar" > < /span>
          </button >
              < /div>
        <div id="navbar" className="collapse navbar-collapse" >
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav" id="center myNavbar">
            <li id="color" ><a href='/my - profile ' id="color">My Profile</a> </li>
            <li><a href=' / pod - search ' id="color">POD Search</a></li>
            <li><a href=' / current - bookings ' id="color">Current Bookings</a> </li>
            <li><a href=' / historic - bookings ' id="color">Historic Bookings</a></li>
            <li><a href=' / contact - us ' id="color">Contact Us</a> </li>
            <li><a href=' / index ' id="color">Log Out</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    
            )}
        });
        
var NavLoggedOut = React.createClass({
    
    render: function() {
    return (
    
        <div className ="navcontainer">
            <nav> 
                <a href=' / pod - search '>POD Search</a>
                <a href=' / contact - us '>Contact Us</a>
                <a href=' / login '>Log In</a>
                <a href=' / pod - profile '>pod profile</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
            )}
        });
  var logged = true;
if (logged) {
    ReactDOM.render(<NavLoggedIn />, document.getElementById('
              navbar '));
} else {
    ReactDOM.render(<NavLoggedOut />, document.getElementById('
              navbar '));
}
```

Also when I click on the hamburger button so many times the nav bar vanishes.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: might be ok in REact - but you have <li id="color"><a href='/my-profile' id="color"> as well as all other li's with the same id of "color" but in this instance you have an li and a a with the same id.

Comment: did you write a `clickHandler`? for buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and worked for me when I switched the data-target field.
Try using this instead.

```
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top  navbar-inverse" id="navColor">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="center myNavbar">
    <li id="color"><a href='/my-profile' id="color">My Profile</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href='/pod-search' id="color">POD Search</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/current-bookings' id="color">Current Bookings</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href='/historic-bookings' id="color">Historic Bookings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='/contact-us' id="color">Contact Us</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href='/index' id="color">Log Out</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See if you are calling first bootstrap and then jquery.
Jquery must be called first and then bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah just checked it.  JQuery is called before Bootstrap.

Comment: This one works for me though. I removed the className things you are using for react etc and followed the way I told you in the begining.
Also, I call first jquery, then bootstrap.min.js and then bootstrap css
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18508/